# How to configure sonarqube to send blocker and crtical issue notification

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, software-quality

I have a requirement that after every scan  send  only sonar blocker and critical violations issues to particular users .

Seeking help to understand the required configuration.
Sonar version is:1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to do it manually then:

1. navigate to the project page on your sonarqube
2. open Issues tab
3. Filter severity (Blocker, Critical)
4. Filter either Assignee or Author
5. Copy URL and send it

Alternatively if users have accounts on sonarqube they can use filter My issues along with filter for severity on the same tab.